# stack time series graph in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I have the following data set:

```
Percentage  Date    Category
0.001546278 1   A
0.002334523 2   A
0.00089928  3   A
0.00205846  4   A
0.000994036 1   B
0.000961275 2   B
6.00E-04    3   B
0.001132153 4   B
0.000773139 1   C
0.000411975 2   C
0.00039968  3   C
0.000205846 4   C
```

which I use to make a graph by:

```
ggplot(data.frame(data), aes(x = Date, y = Percentage, fill = Category)) + 
  geom_area(position = 'stack')
```

what I would like is to get in the x-axes a date instead of the sequence 1-4: i.e.: Jan 2001, Feb 2002, March 2002 and April 2002. Any date format will do, as long as month and year appear. Any suggestions on how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
ggplot(data.frame(data), aes(x = as.Date("2000-12-01")+months(Date), y = Percentage, fill = Category)) + 
  geom_area(position = 'stack') + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y")
```

Comment: thanks very much for your comment. Unfortunately, I come up with the following error: `Error in UseMethod("months") : 
  no applicable method for 'months' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"`. I tried to change the data under Date to the correct format but it seems that it only allows numeric format

Comment: You are right. One has to load `library(lubridate)` beforehand. I falsely assumed base `months` handles it, too..

Answer (score 2):

Use yearmon() function from zoo package.

For example :
Substitute :

```
     x = as.yearmon(as.Date("2015-12-25", %Y-%m-%d),"%y-%m")
```

Comment: how would the function look like?

Comment: `as.yearmon("2015-12-25")` would be sufficient.  Also see `?scale_x_yearmon`